# How to upgrade/install Upstart deamon version 1.5 on Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, service, amazon-ec2, upstart

I instantiate an Amazon Linux machine through EC2 service and the virtual machine already have the "Upstart" daemon, version 0.6.5, installed. How can I upgrade this package to newest version, this case the version 1.5?

`sudo initctl --version` return:

```
initctl (upstart 0.6.5)
Copyright (C) 2010 Canonical Ltd.

This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon actually suggests that you don't in their forums.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=168039

I'm able to get almost everything I need out of upstart 0.65 on Amazon Linux. Though I'm also disappointed you can't upgrade.

`yum upgrade upstart` may work if you have a throw away instance.

Comment: After one year I can't remember the context why I need this. Naturally I found a whay to do what I've wanted.