# Deploying Python flask application using nginx/gunicorn on Amazon Linux EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, flask

I am trying to deploy a python flask app on an Amazon Linux EC2 instance. I am unable to spin up the upstart script and get it running.

I am following this tutorial (which is for ubuntu): https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

My config file looks like: myapp.conf

```
description "Gunicorn application server running myproject"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid user
setgid www-data

env PATH=/home/ec2-user/flask/venv/bin
chdir /home/ec2-user/flask
exec gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:app.sock -m 007 wsgi
```

My wsgi file looks like: wsgi.py

```
from app import application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

My actual application looks like: app.py

```
from flask import Flask
application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route("/")
def hello():
    return ""Hello World"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

When I do a:

```
sudo start myapp
```

I get an error saying unknown job. What exactly do I have to do to get this running? Or is there a different way to make upstart scripts on Amazon Linux instances? Could someone please help

Comment: Hey I face the same issue now. Do you have a solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @das Follow this : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue as well. After some digging, here is what I found.

The `start: Unknown job: myapp` message indicates something wrong with the `Upstart` script `myapp.conf`. You can check the logs by running `sudo tail -n 5 /var/log/messages`

```
init: /etc/init/myapp.conf:7: Unknown stanza
```

In this case, it is having issue with `setuid`. According to [Upstart documentation](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#setuid), `setuid` was added in Upstart v1.4.

Now checking the version of `Upstart` installed by running `initctl --version`. It returned `initctl (upstart 0.6.5)`, which explains why it doesn't work with Amazon Linux. Unfortunately, there seems to be no easy way to [upgrade Upstart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37054283/how-to-upgrade-install-upstart-deamon-version-1-5-on-amazon-linux).

As a proof of concept, you can comment out `setuid` and `setgid` (I also changed the `--bind` parameter)

```
description "Gunicorn application server running myproject"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
#setuid user
#setgid www-data

env PATH=/home/ec2-user/flask/venv/bin
chdir /home/ec2-user/flask
exec gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi
```

And then it should work

```
sudo start myapp
```

However, this is not recommended as it would run `gunicorn` as `root`. And instead of using `setuid` and `setgid`, [Upstart doc](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#run-a-job-as-a-different-user) mentioned that

> if you are not using Upstart 1.4, it is easy to accomplish the
>   required goal. There are a couple of methods you can use. The
>   recommended method for Debian and Ubuntu systems is to use the helper
>   utility start-stop-daemon(8) like this:
>
> `exec start-stop-daemon --start -c myuser --exec command`

Unfortunately, `start-stop-daemon` is not available on Amazon Linux either...There are other possible replacements, such as `daemon` and `runuser`, but at this point I don't think it's worth to pursue using `Upstart`. There are many [other monitoring options](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/deploy.html#monitoring) for `Gunicorn`. I ended up using [`Supervisor`](http://supervisord.org/) instead.

Comment: I ended up using Supervisor as well. My apologies, just saw this update/comment on this post. Using supervisor was much easier.

Comment: Posted a new answer to address the issue of how to set the uid and gid of the gunicorn process to something other than root. Essentially gunicorn offers something like this:
`exec gunicorn --user ec2-user --group www-data --bind socket.sock wsgi`. Easier than Supervisor in my opinion, but other wsgi web servers may not offer this option so supervisor may be a better option for those.

Answer (score 0):

As of the time of this writing, using `gunicorn 19.9.0`, there are the arguments `--user` and `--group` that can be specified with the `gunicorn` command. So, in order to run your gunicorn wsgi server as non-root on amazon linux with upstart 0.6.5 (ie `ec2-user:nginx`), you can specify this in the exec stanza of your upstart script as follows (this example uses a unix socket but an `address:port` will work too:

`exec gunicorn --user ec2-user --group nginx --bind socket.sock wsgi`

Also, in your case, the nginx version that is currently in  the amazon linux yum repo does not use the group `www-data` or the root directory `/var/www/html`. This is the way it exists in the ubuntu apt repo, and is meant to mimic apache. Instead, the amazon linux yum repo uses the group `nginx` and the root directory `/usr/share/nginx/html`. You could set up your system to mimic ubuntu, but this is not the default setup. In that case, just use:

`exec gunicorn --user ec2-user --group www-data --bind socket.sock wsgi`